# How to update one calculated column value or vice-versa?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I'm using Google Spreadsheet to create a two-columns-only converter like this:

```
+--------+-------------+
| Meters | Centimeters |
+--------+-------------+
|      1 |         100 |
|      2 |         200 |
+--------+-------------+
```

When I write a value for meters it should write centimeters and vice-versa: if I write in centimeters column it should update meters value.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- When the value is put to the column "A", you want to put the value to the column "B" by converting the value of column "A".
- When the value is put to the column "B", you want to put the value to the column "A" by converting the value of column "B".

In this case, I thought that when the OnEdit trigger is used, your goal might be able to be achieved. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor and save it. And, in order to run the script, please put a value to the column "A" or "B". By this, the script is automatically run by the OnEdit trigger.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name you want to use.
  const range = e.range;
  if (range.getSheet().getSheetName() != sheetName) return;
  const value = range.getValue();
  if (range.columnStart == 1) {
    range.offset(0, 1).setValue(value * 100);
  } else if (range.columnStart == 2) {
    range.offset(0, -1).setValue(value / 100);
  }
}
```

#### Result:

When above script is used, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [offset(rowOffset, columnOffset)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset)